Stored procedure error in Synapse Analytics pipeline for SQL serverless pool
I have created a stored procedure inside ForEach pipeline in Azure Synapse Analytics. When I run the pipeline, I get this error:

"errorCode": "2011",
"message": "Content of directory on path 'https://adventurerasseldata.dfs.core.windows.net/adventure-gold/SalesLT/Address/ProductDescription/_delta_log/.' cannot be listed.",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "Stored procedure to get table name",

According to Microsoft, the solution is to grant yourself the Storage Blob Data Contributor role in the storage account you're trying to query. I did that but I still get the error.
enter image description here
